# Discrete Math (checking over quantified symbolic logic problems)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I'm preparing for a midterm and would like to ensure that I'm writing statements in quantified symbolic logic properly.

*Since I'm only seeking someones expertise to check over my work, I can delete this afterwards since it's not really a question.*

Let A(x) represent “x is high quality”, B(x) “x looks good”, C(x, y) “x is faster than y”, and D(x, y)
“x is cheaper than y”. Translate the following statements into quantified symbolic logic, using the
set of all cars S as the domain.

(a) All high quality cars look good.

- ∀x ∈ S, A(x) ^ B(x)

(b) There are no good-looking cars.

- ~∃x ∈ S, B(x)

(c) The faster a car is, the more expensive it is.

- ∃x,y ∈ S C(x,y) ⟹ D(x,y)

(d) There is a cheapest car.

- ∃x ∈ S, D(x,S) *Would this work, I'm not too sure about it?*

(e) Some good-looking cars are not high quality.

- ∃x ∈ S, B(x) ⟹ A(x)

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Do yourself a favor and choose reasonable variable names.  $Q$ for quality, $G$ for looks Good, $F$ for faster, $C$ for cheaper.  Don't make things harder than they have to be.

Comment: I agree, I did not generate this question though xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) is not right ... your statement says that *every* car is a high-quality car that looks good. ... use a conditional!

b) is correct

c) you need some operator between $C(x,y)$ and $D(x,y)$ ... also think about the order of the arguments: which is more expensive than which?

your d) is not grammatical : $S$ is used for the domain ... you can't use it inside a predicate ... try again

e) again you need to add some operator ... indeed, this statement clearly needs a negation somewhere ...

Comment: e) also should not be a conditional.

Comment: **a)** ∀x ∈ S, A(x) ⟹ B(x)

**c)** **D(y,x)** - Accidently typed that part out wrong; I'm unsure of the operator to use?

What would the proper answer for **d** and **e** look like?

Thank you!

Comment: @I'mHungry But now you don't have an operator connecting $A(x)$ and $B(x)$. OK, a) should be $\forall x (A(x) \rightarrow B(x))$ .. d) is the trickiest ... but can you try e) yourself?

Comment: @Bram28 Ahh, so **e)** ∃x( B(x) → ~A(x) ) ?? d is scary xD

Comment: @I'mHungry As a rule of thumb, an existential hardly ever goes together with a conditional ... and the same goes for this one: you end up saying that there is something such that if it is a good looking car, then it is not a quality car ... but that would be true for anything that is not a good -looking car. So ... try a different operator here ...

Comment: @Bram28 That makes sense, I'll be sure to remember that rule of thumb. Can I use the for all operator instead, ∀x( B(x) → ~A(x) ) ? I just feel as though 'for all' does not replace 'some'. Thank you

Comment: @I'mHungry Right, for e) you definitely want to use an $\exists$, not a $\forall$, so try again.  Talking about quantifiers though, what about c)? Do you think this is a statement about some cars or is this a general statement about all cars?